# Exchange rates for ENDOFMONTH

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, currency-exchange-rates

I have an Exchange Rate table that I'm trying to get the ending months calculation

It's using a minimum of 3 currencies lets use GBP USD EUR

I need to return when selecting that currency the End of month Currency

So something like k

```
EOMCcy=:IF(HASONEVALUE('Ccy'[Currency Symbol]), 
CALCULATE([Exchange Rate],ENDOFMONTH('Exchange Rates'[Date]) ,BLANK()))
```

I know I need to validate the currency somewhere and I'm trying many thinks as I have a fromCcy and toCccy column  e.g GBP USD 
This would show in the [Exchange Rate] column =1.22

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction or offer a better method with my code

Thank all

Comment: Could you edit to include sample data and expected result in your question? It is hard to understand your problem with that short description.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I solved it

```
    EOMCcy:=IF(HASONEVALUE('Ccy'[Currency Symbol]),

CALCULATE (
    SUM ([ExchangeRate]),
    FILTER (
         ALL ( 'Exchange Rates'[Date]),
         'Exchange Rates'[Date] = ENDOFMONTH('Exchange Rates'[Date])
     )
 ),BLANK())
```